# SSRS - Suddenly the report only shows "No Data Available"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

To get the data for my report I use a stored procedure.

One of the SP parameters is called "date" and was unused until yesterday, when I added a report parameter called "date" which passes a date value to the SP.

But after that the chart in my report only showed the message "No data available."
So I set the report parameter "date" back to NULL so the SP ignores the "date" parameter (like it was before). But the chart still shows "No data available".

When I execute the SP (with and without "date" parameter) the SP delievers data.

I have no idea, why the report doesn't show the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the SSRS interface is not passing the DATE value in the format your SP is expecting. I would use SQL Profiler to find the exact parameter format which SSRS is passing. From there, you can edit the SP or report as needed.

Comment: After some issues with the datatype "date" we now use a varchar for the date parameter (I know, not the best solution...)

But when the DATE value is NOT used, it also doesn't work. So I guess there must be another problem

Comment: And the SP date parameter is also varchar

Comment: What happens in your SP when the varchar parameter with a value of NULL is passed to it?

Comment: When NULL is passed to it, it "ignores" the parameter and doesn't filter the data for the date.

Comment: Is it varchar(10)? Are you sure there are not blank spaces?

Comment: Yes, it's varchar(10). There shouldn't be blank spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.

I must confess that the problem was not the date parameter. Thanks to the SQL Server Profiler I discovered that another parameter was the reason why I got no data.